# Проблема с библиотекой (.NET)

Tags: .net, microsoft-store

Декомпилировал с помощью JetBrains dotPeek 1.4.2 приложение VK из Windows Store и экспортировал в Visual Studio 2013. Не могу понять, что не так с библиотекой Windows, подключить тоже не получается. В чем проблема?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Удалите эту библиотеку, запустите сборку проекта, посмотрите на что ругнется, добавьте нужную библиотеку.

Comment: @hardsky эта библиотека и нужна.
Она используется:

    `using Windows.UI;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;`

Только добавить не могу, через Add reference ее нет.

Comment: @thejadefalcon могу предположить, что у вас по умолчанию стоит не та версия .net или тип проекта не тот - не установлены инструменты для разработки под windows phone. Лично я не вижу эту сборку вообще из проекта wpf под .net 4.5

Comment: @thejadefalcon, посмотрите подробности про эти неймспейсы в msdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно подключить Windows.winmd
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls
@RussCoder правильно пишет: проверить что вы на вин8, проверить тип проекта, проверить наличие сдк.